# display json results with angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm trying get some json data from a web api. So far Ive gotten the response from the api, Now i'm trying to target a value and insert that value at the end of the youtube link.

```
movie.component.html

<div *ngIf="movie">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{movie.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <img class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Genres:<span *ngFor="let genre of movie.genres"> {{genre.name}}</span></li>
                    <li class="list-group-rel">Release Date: {{movie.release_date | date}}</li>
                </ul>
                <p>{{movie.overview}}</p>
                <br>
                **<div *ngIf="videos">
                 <div *ngFor="let video of videos">
                 <iframe width="360" height="215" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video.key}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>**
                </div>
                </div>
                <h4>Rating</h4>
                <p>{{movie.vote_average}} / 10</p>
                <a *ngIf="movie.homepage" href="{{movie.homepage}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default">Visit Movie Website</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

-----------------
movie.component.ts

export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {


movie:Object;
videos: Object;

constructor(private router:ActivatedRoute, private _movieService:MovieService) 
{ 

}

ngOnInit() {

this.router.params.subscribe((params) =>{
    let id = params['id'];
    this._movieService.getMovie(id).subscribe(movie =>{
        this.movie = movie;
  });
});
   this.router.params.subscribe((params) =>{
  let id = params['id'];
  this._movieService.getTrailer(id).subscribe(videos =>{
    this.videos = videos;
    });
});
}

}
```

this is the response from Api, I'm trying to target the "key" value and insert it at the end of the youtube link
[image: this is the response from Api, I'm trying to target the "key" value and insert it at the end of the youtube link]

but i get this error
[image: but i get this error]

Comment: how you are assigning videos in ts file?

Comment: post your code in the question

Comment: videos: Object;

Comment: Post your JSON and the relevant typescript code.

Comment: i posted some of the ts file if that helps

Answer (score 1):

the problem here that your are using *ngFor for an Object.

> *ngFor: is used to iterate arrays.

now the response you have is an object, inside this object you have an array **result** i believe this is the array you want to iterate.

you just need to change the *ngFor in your template.

```
...
 <div *ngFor="let video of videos.results">
...
```

Comment: thanks,I have a question about the arrays. I notice that there are two arrays for this result. How can I iterate only the first array? I tried to do video[0].key but that isn't working

Comment: I had to add a bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.... but the video still doesn't show